# Context menu shell execution code page

Tags: shell, registry

How to set code page for **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/*/shell/do something/command** execution in registry (context menu for files).

The default is **850**. I want to set it up to **852**. The current command is:

*"C:\Program Files\Pro\P\p.exe" "%1"*

No integration to p.exe is allowed just the script above to be changed.

Comment: Is p a console or gui application

Comment: Maybe **runas** with **chcp** option could solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When a thread is created, it uses the user locale.

You cannot override locale for specific process, esp. through a registry setting. `SetThreadLocale` API is perhaps all you have and even with it - be sure to read its [Remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) section on MSDN.